# Inline JavaScript enable/disable select and text box on click radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying inline script  to enable disable with radio button, but it is not working. How to do that?

```
<form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="ph" onclick=" document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=true;" value="Disable list">DISABLE
<input type="radio" name="ph" onclick="enable()" value="Enable list">ENABLE
</form>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Simple problem of mismatch quotes in your html

Comment: i m tring inline  like css work, have you idea  using script inline ????

Comment: i dont want to use function.

Comment: @ charlietfl thnx  .it worked.

Comment: @biffen everyone is not smart as you.

Comment: @AKEELAHMED I *really* don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even see it at the syntax highlighter. Your JavaScript in the onclick event contains `"`, but they're special characters for HTML. You have to escape them with backslashes like

`<tag onclick="alert(\"hello\");">`